# bundle update error - cannot find gem "config" from rails github?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Was having trouble installing bundle, finally got it to work but it returns this error:

```
bundle update
Fetching git://github.com/laserlemon/figaro.git 
Fetching git://github.com/railsconfig/config.git  
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............  
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...  
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..  
**Could not find gem 'config' in git://github.com/railsconfig/config.git (at
master@0b3d9c1).
Source contains 'config' at: 1.0.0**
```

I'm just learning Ruby on Rails so any help would be really appreciated.. Would I have to change the path to the 'config' gem? I'm pretty lost at this point.

Comment: Please post contents of your GemFile. Probably you have config set to X and version in GemFile and told it to fetch from GitHub directly, while at GitHub this gem has alrdy Y version.

Comment: gem 'config', github:'railsconfig/config'


i'm guessing this is the relevant line? so, would i want to change the second part of this line to something including 1.0.0? eg: ">= 1.0.0"

Comment: Do you need to get it from GitHub instead of RubyGems for some reason? If not, i suggest just use rubygems `gem 'config', '~> 1.0.0'`

Comment: @janesmith post your Gemfile content , that would be helpful